# VBscript Picture.Insert does not save the picture

Tags: excel, image, vbscript, insert

I have a VBScript and a method that inserts a picture from a .jpeg file into and excel sheet. I will like for the picture to save to the excel sheet so that when the excel file is sent to another person, they can view the picture.
 I have noticed that picture links to the local folder on my computer from which i copied it.

Is there a way to save the inserted picture to be part of the Excel document?

This is my method

```
 set attachment = .Pictures.Insert(path)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Shapes.AddPicture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198302%28v=office.15%29.aspx) Method has a parameter to specify whether

> To save the picture with the document.

[This solution](http://www.ms-office-forum.net/forum/showpost.php?s=0f99cebbff53a96188815e22575e6289&p=1378805&postcount=4) to the same problem replaces .Insert with .AddPictured successfully (German, sorry).

Comment: Thanks this helped. I guess the Picture does not have a similar  to save the picture.